# How to color for every array of x, y points in the list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have fallowing problem:

I have a list of arrays with x, y points, e.g. 100 arrays with a shape of (400, 2) (or just array of shape `(100, 400, 2)`), where the last dimension corresponds to the x, y coordinates. I would like to colour the every array with a different colour from a colour gradient, like the plot below:

[image]

So points that corresponds to the 0, 1, 2 ... 10 have colours from violet to blue, from the 10 to the 100 are green to yellow etc.

I tried with the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

N = 100
my_cord = np.stack([np.random.randn(400, 2) + np.random.randn(1, 2)*10 for j in range(N)])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('spring', N)
for i in range(N):
    x, y = my_cord[i].T
    cf = ax.scatter(x, y, cmap=cmap(i))

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=N)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(sm)


ax.set_xlabel('IC 1')
ax.set_ylabel('IC 2')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

but I'm getting different scatterplot colours than defined in the cmap:

[image]

Comment: Set an alpha/transparency value of the colours.

Comment: @KonradRudolph But then, points will "fade away" or you mean something ?

Comment: `cf = ax.scatter(x, y, color=cmap(i))` Isn't this the correct setting?

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks, it works! Could you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @DanielWiczew The fading is the whole point, yes. Look at the original plot: the colours fade away towards the edges, you only get solid colour where lots of points partially overlap each other. I don’t think *all* colours in the original plot have an alpha component: the purple points are sufficiently sparse, and maybe the other colours are also solid; but the black is definitely (very) transparent.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the point (transparency), Konrad. Definitely, there's transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the discrete colors here, you will need to modify the following.

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('spring', N)
for i in range(N):
    x, y = my_cord[i].T
    cf = ax.scatter(x, y, color=cmap(i))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As your colorbar is logarithmic, it makes sense to use a `LogNorm`.  The size of the dots can be made smaller. For very small dots, the outline should be removed (e.g. setting `ec='none'`).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

N = 100
my_cord = np.stack([np.random.randn(400, 2) + np.random.randn(1, 2) * 10 for j in range(N)])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('spring', N)
norm = mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=N + 1)
for i in range(N):
    cf = ax.scatter(my_cord[i, :, 0], my_cord[i, :, 1], color=cmap(norm(i + 1)), ec='none', marker=',', s=1)

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(sm)

ax.set_xlabel('IC 1')
ax.set_ylabel('IC 2')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot with lognorm colors]

PS: The plot can also be created in one go by using the index as `c=` and directly passing the `cmap`:

```py
norm = mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=N + 1)
cf = ax.scatter(my_cord[:, :, 0], my_cord[:, :, 1],
                c=np.repeat(np.arange(1, N + 1), my_cord.shape[1]),
                cmap='spring', ec='none', marker=',', s=1)
plt.colorbar(cf)
```